# Possible infinite loop in mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am working on overhauling the URL structure of review pages, which can be filtered by city, county, # of stars and technician. I want to make the pages look like they are static HTML pages as well as replace pluses with hyphens.
My goal:
-Apply the new style URL's without modifying the reviews page, just the htaccess file
-Set up 301 redirects from the old style URLs to new style URLs
-Convert pluses to hyphens

Currently the review URLs look like this:

> domain.com/reviews/?city=City+Name
>
> domain.com/reviews/?city=City+Name&page=2
>
> domain.com/reviews/?county=County+Name
>
> domain.com/reviews/?county=County+Name&page=2
>
> domain.com/reviews/?stars=4
>
> domain.com/reviews/?stars=4&page=2
>
> domain.com/reviews/?tech=Tech+Name
>
> domain.com/reviews/?tech=Tech+Name&page=2

My goal is to make them look like this (and 301 the old style URLs to the new style URLs):

> domain.com/reviews/city/City-Name.html
>
> domain.com/reviews/city/City-Name/page/2.html
>
> domain.com/reviews/county/County-Name.html
>
> domain.com/reviews/county/County-Name/page/2.html
>
> domain.com/reviews/stars/4.html
>
> domain.com/reviews/stars/4/page/2.html
>
> domain.com/reviews/tech/Tech-Name.html
>
> domain.com/reviews/tech/Tech-Name/page/2.html

City, county and tech names don't always contain pluses (ie Boston vs New+York) and some have more than one plus. Currently this is what I have to mask the old style URLs with new style URLs (and this works fine btw):

```
##FIRST PAGE REVIEWS (ie. reviews/city/city-name.html)
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\.html "/reviews/?$1=$2+$3+$4+$5+$6" [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\.html "/reviews/?$1=$2+$3+$4+$5" [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\.html "/reviews/?$1=$2+$3+$4" [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/(.*)\-(.*)\.html "/reviews/?$1=$2+$3" [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/(.*)\.html "/reviews/?$1=$2" [NC,L]

##PAGINATED REVIEWS (ie. reviews/city/city-name/page/2.html)
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)/page/(.*)\.html "/reviews/?$1=$2+$3+$4+$5+$6&page=$7" [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)/page/(.*)\.html "/reviews/?$1=$2+$3+$4+$5&page=$6" [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)/page/(.*)\.html "/reviews/?$1=$2+$3+$4&page=$5" [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/(.*)\-(.*)/page/(.*)\.html "/reviews/?$1=$2+$3&page=$4" [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)/(.*)/page/(.*)\.html "/reviews/?$1=$2&page=$3" [NC,L]
```

The part that I am having trouble with is 301-ing the OLD style URLs to the NEW style URLs. This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*) /reviews/%1/%2.html? [NS,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)=(.*)&page=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*) /reviews/%1/%2/page/%3.html? [NS,R=301,NC]
```

When I try this FireFox gives me the "The page isn't redirecting properly" error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is probably an infinite loop. Use *THE_REQUEST* instead to inspect the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\?([^=]+)=([^\ ]*)&page=([^\ ]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^reviews/ /reviews/%1/%2/page/%3.html? [NS,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\?([^=]+)=([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^reviews/ /reviews/%1/%2.html? [NS,R=301,NC]
```

Note that this will fail if the number or order of parameters is different than this.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you that worked. The only thing is I would need to to convert the pluses to hyphens. Currently "/reviews/?city=City+Name" will take you to "/reviews/city/City+Name.html" where it should be "...City-Name.html". Also is there a way to convert everything to lowercase?

Comment: @Yevgeniy Женя Van Chuchin: Although this is possible with mod_rewrite, it is rather complicated as you can only replace a fixed amount of occurrences at a time (see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791548/mod-rewrite-rule-to-enforce-canonical-percent-encoding/3806538#3806538). A higher level language is way better to do this kind of work.

Comment: I am fine with a fixed amount. 5 occurrences is plenty, this is what I am doing in the first part (masking old style URLs with new style).

Comment: @Yevgeniy Женя Van Chuchin: You *can* replace an arbitrary number of occurrences; but only a fixed number at a time. That step will then just be repeated. But that is complicated and is not recommended. Why don’t you use a higher level language to do that?

Comment: I figured that it can all be done via htaccess, and since the amount of occurrences would be very limited, I would rather just do it the "non-recommended" way - as long as it works. What 'higher level' language would I use?

Comment: @Yevgeniy Женя Van Chuchin: Well, what language do you use to process the requests?

Comment: I am using PHP, and I can easily have it replace +'s with -'s but for SEO purposes I do not want to have two versions of each page indexed (reviews/city/City-Name.html) and (reviews/city/City+Name.html). Translating and processing on the php end is simple, it's the htaccess file I'm having trouble with >_<

Comment: @Gumbo: I figured out how to do it via htaccess. I really appreciate all your help!!